# Redux Dev Tools reporting <UNDEFINED> type

Tags: redux

I am relatively new to Redux but I'm finding that in a few cases the devtools report an Action *type* of `<UNDEFINED>` and yet by printing to console immediately before dispatch (in the action creator) I see that the object does indeed have it's type:

[image]

[image: console output]

Has anyone else seen this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

It just means that the action type is not serialized via `JSON.stringify`. Most likely you're using ES6 Symbol as type. So, `JSON.stringify({ type: Symbol('BECOMES_UNDEFINED') }) === '{}'`.

If you want Redux DevTools Extension to support unserializable data, set [`serialize` parameter](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/docs/API/Arguments.md#serialize) to `true`:

```
const store = Redux.createStore(reducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__({
   serialize: true
}));
```

It will handle dates, regexes, undefined, error objects, symbols and functions.

Comment: well my `type` is just a _String_ but I did try the setting anyway on the off chance that that would help but seemed to have no impact.

Comment: If you could [open an issue](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues) with an example to reproduce (or provide a jsfiddle here), I'd look into it.

Comment: Ok, this particular example here is closed-source but if I can reproduce it externally I will raise the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've imported the action as an function, try to call (payload) might solve your issue